# Why to create sub namespace like Product.Core for application's business logic instead of "root namespace" Product?

Tags: c#, oop, architecture, namespaces

I'm wondering why the most common stuff/basic logic is not just put to Product. Is creating Product.Core and putting nothing directly in Product done only to imply what classes are really about? Is there any "rules"/best practices about this?

It's a simple question, but I'm not sure if my writing make any sense.

EDIT: If I have 3 things to divide in namespaces: GUI, DataAccess and Business logic and decide to have classes in 3 namespaces. First 2 are obvious:

Product.UI

Product.DataAccess

However business logic can be put either to

Product.Core

or

Product

Now I would like to know which is more "standard": Having Business logic in Product or  in Product.Core.

In case of putting Business logic classes in Product there would be no Product.Core.

If putting Business logic classes in Product.Core the Product would contain no classes.

Both approaches can have some benefits and I would like to know what people think.

Comment: I think answers to this question are going to be highly opinionated. From MS: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229026

Comment: where are you getting this information anyway?  I've often seen "Product" used, and other times "Product.Core"

Comment: @Kritner: getting what information? i have no information. that's why i'm asking is there any best practice / common way to do this. i've also seen both.

Comment: i'm not implying either is more common or anything, i'm trying to understand/guessing motives for putting common stuff/business logic to Product.Core instead of just putting it to "root".

Comment: Wait, do you mean why do people have a "deep" namespace to begin with? i.e: `namespace MyCompany.MyProduct` vs `namespace MyProduct` ?

Comment: oh i'm terrible explaining. i try to edit my question. i knew i asked  it badly. please wait.

Answer (score 0):

There is some good discussion here https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40394/how-do-you-organize-your-projects about that.

One point is to separate the solution as much as you need to for further expansion - but it is generally easier to refactor on the fly as you need to. Otherwise, there are two main reasons to separate projects:

**1. Following a separation of concerns paradigm**
For example in a simple web project, I would have 2 projects `Project` and `Project.Core`. This allows me to keep all the data, logic and code in one project while keeping all the web stuff in another.

**2. Having shared code amongst individual consumer/frontend applications**
If you plan on having a web application and a windows service for instance, you are going to have common code in the realm of services and data access. Instead of duplicating this code you can move it to a common library so that both applications can take advantage of the same code.

Comment: thanks! good points here! not really what i tried to ask. I actually happened to read your link before asking. it does not really address Product vs. Product.Core though.

Comment: The points to take home are really in the vein of "what works for you". I have seen layouts from monster projects all in one project that are a nightmare to navigate to projects that are so separated that you have to reference so much stuff in all projects that it is basically pointless. Personally I follow the `Project`/`Project.Core` paradigm until I absolutely *have* to split them. Keeping it simple is the best structure you will ever have.

Comment: thanks! so you have classes both in Project and Project.Core? I was thinking that I either have all common/business logic either in Project (and not have Project.Core at all) or have all common/business logic in Project.Core and Project has no classes.

Comment: So `Project` would be what they call "Presentation Layer". It provides the UI and stuff like that that the **user** interacts with. `Project.Core` provides all the classes that the **program** interacts with. This would be the business logic, data model, services, etc... You can then at a later date separate the `Project.Core` into `Project.Core.Data`, `Project.Core.Services`, etc... It is all about separating your blocks. Although, there is nothing stopping you from separating it into these namespaces inside the Core project from the beginning. In fact I would suggest it.